# Unable to provision Secure Store Service Application SharePoint 2013. I get TLS related error

Tags: sharepoint-server, secure-store, tls

I am Unable to provision Secure Store Service Application for SharePoint 2013. I get TLS related error. Below is the error:

Logging unknown/unexpected client side exception: SecurityNegotiationException. This will cause this application server to be removed from the load balancer queue. Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'sm000000:32844'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()     at System.Serv...                f968df9e-3ece-009d-d25e-28f479736e4a

Comment: Have you validated your TLS config? Turn on CAPI2 logs in Windows Event Viewer and try to recreate the error you should get more information about the nature of the issue. But it looks like one of the components is not configured for TLS (or miscofigured)

Comment: I have enabled CAPI2 logs. Below is the log I am getting:

Comment: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Comment: Try exporting root and adding it to trusted root on the servers.

Comment: It is already there.

Comment: Hi Dharam, were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: We need to enable support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2 for which please follow below Microsoft article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by enableing SharePoint support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2 by following [Enable TLS and SSL support in SharePoint 2013](http://us/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013) article.

Answer (score 0):

There a blog about configuring Secure Store Service Application, you can check it with your steps.
[How To Configure Secure Store Service Application In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-configure-secure-store-service-application/)

If this issue still exists, you could provide your steps to analysis this issue further.

Comment: I have followed steps in the article mentioned by you but still I am facing the same issue.